# What is the correct way to remove an Onsen UI component from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I'm new to Onsen UI and currently using version 2.0.0-rc.15. What is the correct way to remove an Onsen UI component (e.g. `<ons-progress-bar>`, `<ons-button>`) from the DOM using vanilla JavaScript (or jQuery)? Do we remove it like how we remove a HTML element?

Comment: Yes.  Now I assume that you are referring to individual elements but not templates or pages as those have methods available such as `popPage()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Munsterlander. I want to remove a <ons-progress-bar>, I was wondering whether `$('#theOnsProgressBarId').remove();` is sufficient.